# Identificar vazamento de memória em c++?

Tags: c++, debug, gerenciamento-de-memória

Olá, recentemente tenho tido problemas com a aplicação que estou desenvolvendo. A aplicação parece perder performance durante um certo tempo de execução. Verifiquei meu código porém utilizo apenas um único objeto alocado dinamicamente na memória, e estou chamando seu devido destrutor eventualmente, mas o problema persiste. Pelo projeto no momento possuir muitas chamadas de objetos, creio que esteja acontecendo algum vazamento de memória em alguma parte do código. 
A minha dúvida é, existe alguma ferramenta para detectar vazamentos de memória (*memory leaks*), e informar em que parte do código está ocorrendo? Li em alguns lugares sobre o Valgrind, porém só é compativel com a plataforma linux. No momento estou utilizando a IDE Qt creator no Windows, com o projeto em modo Debug.
Alguém saberia da existencia de alguma ferramenta parecida ou como identificar esses vazamentos de memória? Desde já, agradeço.

Obs: Tentei depurar o código utilizando o próprio Qt creator, porém tive problemas com a Ide, e o programa simplesmente nao depura.

Comment: Yuri, na sua pergunta o título diz uma coisa e o corpo diz outra. Você quer ajuda para identificar o vazamento ou quer dicas de ferramentas? Se for a primeira opção, procure fornecer os trechos de código relevantes (principalmente onde há alocação e onde ela é chamada/invocada). Se for a segunda, eu temo que isso não faz parte do escopo do site. Você pode solicitar ajuda com dicas assim no [chat].

Comment: Analisarei com mais calma e tentarei depurar meu código para fornecer um cenário melhor para falar do meu problema, Porque no meu projeto atual, existem muitas chamadas de objetos, porém apenas 1 deles é stack. Tentarei fornecer uma pergunta melhor em breve. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma lista de ferramentas livres capazes de verificar a memória em tempo de execução (*runtime*) e apontar onde está o provável *leak*:

**1) Dr. Memory**: http://code.google.com/p/drmemory/

**2) UMDH**: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343

**3) Application Verifier**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371695%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**4) Visual Leak Detector for Visual C++ 2008-2015**: https://kinddragon.github.io/vld/

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado, irei conferir as sugestões e ver qual delas melhor funciona. Grato pela resposta.

Comment: @Yuri_Pires: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-analyzer.html

Comment: neste tutorial ele utiliza o valgrind q só está disponivel para linux, no momento estou utlizando o windows :/

Comment: Acabou que nenhum dos programas funcionaram muito bem pra mim, mas deixarei como resposta ao post, pois pode ajudar outras pessoas com problema semelhante, Obrigado!